# How to select grouped greater values from list with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have object list (name is list) with e.g. next values:

```
[0] {Id='04239',Color='03',MatPre='145698',Stz=210,Spp=1}
[1] {Id='04239',Color='03',MatPre='145698',Stz=210,Spp=3}
[2] {Id='04239',Color='KB',MatPre='145698',Stz=210,Spp=3}
[3] {Id='04239',Color='KB',MatPre='145698',Stz=210,Spp=2}
[4] {Id='04239',Color='03',MatPre='145698',Stz=210,Spp=4}
```

Result or new list that I whant to get is list with v items:

```
[0] {Id='04239',Color='03',MatPre='145698',Stz=210,Spp=3}
[1] {Id='04239',Color='03',MatPre='145698',Stz=210,Spp=4}
[2] {Id='04239',Color='KB',MatPre='145698',Stz=210,Spp=3}
```

I would need something like this

```
var test = list.GroupBy(x => new { x.Color })
               .Where(x => x.Spp is greater than first 
                                 smaller x.Spp in same 
                                 group of Color)
               .SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it, although calling `Min` every time might not be efficient, you might consider query syntax to make it better:

```
list.GroupBy(x => x.Color)
    .SelectMany(g => g.Where(x => x.Spp > g.Min(_ => _.Spp));
```